# Telethon or Aiogram, pros and cons, which is better?

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon, aiogram

Can anyone tell about pros and cons about Telethon and Aiogram?

Now I'm using Telethon but in some cases I see people using Aiogram.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Aiogram** is Telegram BOT API Lib, **Telethon** is MTPROTO Lib, off course **Telethon** is better now , Yo can see The difference between both is [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/botapi-vs-mtproto.html)

Comment: While MTProto gives access to the entirety of Telegram's API with less restrictions than the HTTP bot API, and in theory has less overhead, there are still some API limits in place which neither can avoid. You might find either library simpler, so it's mostly preference.